# Beautiful Soup, scraping an auction site that clears the sold item div on completion of auction

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

ran into a problem with a scraper I'm building.  I wanted to scrape information from an auction site.  The issue is when I request the html I have to refresh the page, when you refresh this auction site page any items auction items that have ended are removed so I lose the data I was looking to get.

```
def soldDetection(soup):
    #Select the timer and check if it == "Lot Closed" once lot is closed send the entire container information to getData() to extract price and details
    while True:
        getPage(url)
        container = soup.find_all('li', class_='current-price')
        #print(container)
        for child in container:
            label = child.span.contents[0]
            #print (label)
            if label == 'Closing bid':
                # grab entire div for the card with data for the getData()
                print('Found')
                parentDiv = label.find_parent('div', class_='lot-single')
                getData(parentDiv)
                return parentDiv
            else:
                continue
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Nothing Sold')
        continue
```

In my browser if I don't refresh the 'current-price' span content changes from "Current bid" to "Closing bid"  but if I refresh that item is cleared from the html.  Is there a way to get beautiful soup to watch this without refreshing and clearing?  I am concerned that bs4 might not be the right tool for this job, if so what tool should I use?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution,  I used selenium to open a browser and watch for the changes that javascript was sending to the page. Then collected all the html and sent it to my beautiful soup function to navigate the tree.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(websiteAddress)
...
      elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Closing bid')]")
        if not elems:
            print('Not Found')
            continue
        label = elems[0].text
        if label == 'Closing bid':
            # grab entire div for the card with data for the getData()
            soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'html.parser')
```